# Firebird 2.5 drop constraint error

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I'm using Firebird 2.5.4 on WinXP.
I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE_1"
(
  "ID" "D_ID" NOT NULL,
  ...
  "WHATEVER" VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET WIN1250 COLLATE PXW_HUN,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT "C_MY_TABLE_1_U1" UNIQUE ("WHATEVER"),
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

I want to drop the "C_MY_TABLE_1_U1" constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE_1 DROP CONSTRAINT C_MY_TABLE_1_U1;
```

Then I got this error:

```
unsuccessful metadata update
ERASE RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS failed
index unexpectedly deleted
At trigger 'RDB$TRIGGER_19'
At trigger 'RDB$TRIGGER_11'
```

Where do I fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database was corrupted, after a backup/restore I was able to drop the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I've added

```
CREATE DOMAIN "D_ID" BIGINT;
```

as it is requierd to test ypur script and get no error (FB 2.5.4).

Can you be more specific about OS / FB version on which you get the error ?

```
CREATE DOMAIN "D_ID" BIGINT;
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE_1"
(
   "ID" "D_ID" NOT NULL,
   "WHATEVER" VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET WIN1250 COLLATE PXW_HUN,
   CONSTRAINT "C_MY_TABLE_1_U1" UNIQUE ("WHATEVER"),
   PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE_1 DROP CONSTRAINT C_MY_TABLE_1_U1;
```

Comment: Firebird-2.5.4.26856 & Win32. I think my database corrupted on some way.